# Sending Data from Rails to AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Given that you have a Rails application with a controller action `#index`, how would I be able to give that `@items` to Angular in the view without having to having tons of javascript logic within the index view?

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
end
```

And the view would be:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Key Question**: What is a good practice to have that data listed via Angular that was passed to the view by Rails?

Answer (score 0):

In the **index** action you would want to respond with json or javascript:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @items }
    format.js
  end
end
```

On the angular side you can use the **$http service** to make an **XHR** or **JSONP** request to the items url. More infos in the docs: [$http-service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

Example from the docs:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/items'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

There is also a nice railscast on this subject: [AngularJS Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs)

Comment: I don't want to convert the app into an API. I also don't want to have to set all of this up. This looks way to much for a simple `ng-repeat`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way than that. If you want to make  standard JS or jQuery Ajax calls, you also have to do it this way...

Comment: But I don't want to do Ajax calls. I just want to hand Angular data from Rails. Like I'm not making an Angular App with Rails, I have a Rails app with some Angular.

Comment: And where did you instantiate the angular module, controller and the scope for items? Maybe you want to look at the Railscast I mentioned at the end of my answer.